# Php extends from different class runtime (extends as variable?)

Tags: php, class, variables, inheritance

This is going to be strange. I have a database class for MySQL, and independent classes. For example:

```
class users extends MySQL
```

this class is a general class for users, so that it can be used more times.
But occasionally, an "MySQL_DEBUGGED" class is present, and if so, I want to extend from it:

```
class users extends MySQL_DEBUGGED
```

I want to inherit MySQL_DEBUGGED if present, otherwise MySQL class. If I put it into variable, it drops an error. How to do it?

Comment: may i ask you why do you have two different classes (MYSQL and MYSQL_DEBUGGED)? it seems to me that the problem is that you have two classes instead of just one that can be configured to be more verbose (ie: to debug) or not

Comment: i don't know what are you doing but if you have two classes only because of debugging, you should be using a logger (ie: log4php) and configure it for your needs

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can inherit from a class which name is not written in the PHP script.

A possible solution would be :

- to define two classes, both called `MySQL`, in two separate files
- make your `users` class always extend the `MySQL` class *(which means one of those two)*
- Depending on the situation, include :

  - the file that contains the "production" `MySQL` class,
  - or the file that contains the "development" `MySQL` class

This way, your class always extends a `MySQL` class -- but you'll include the *right one*.

Basically, in your main file, you'd have :

```
if (DEBUG) {
    require __DIR__ . '/MySQL-debug.php';
}
else {
    require __DIR__ . '/MySQL-production.php';
}

class users extends MySQL {
    // ...
}
```

And both `MySQL-debug.php` and `MySQL-production.php` will contain a class called `MySQL` -- which would not contain the same stuff in both files, of course.

Comment: this looks better, but MySQL-debug inherits MySQL-production :) so class names cant be the same

Comment: @deeped humph, too bad ; and what about having both MySQL-debug and MySQL-production extend a common MySQL-common class, that would contain all the common code ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to have an empty "bridge" class and inherit always from that one.

Then, the only class that you would need to have declared twice would be the empty one.

```
if (class_exists('MySQL_DEBUGGED')) {
  class MySQLBridge extends MySQL { }
} else {
  class MySQLBridge extends MySQL_DEBUGGED { }
}

class User extends MySQLBridge {
  // ... your code ...
}
```

And finally on your pages:

```
require_once('User.php');
$user = new User();
```

Other suggested solutions require you to have two copies of your inherited class, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) function.

```
if (class_exists('MySQL_DEBUGGED')) {
    class users extends MySQL_DEBUGGED {
        ....
    }
} else {
    class users extends MySQL {
        ....
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it though.  Conditionally declaring classes seems like a nightmare.

Comment: thats right, but then all the methods must be copy/pasted, thats what I want to avoid